# Constructing conditional logic from kwargs

Tags: python, image-processing

I am a bit stumped something i would think is possible with kwargs but i cant seem to find a way to do.

In brief i have a variable that is instantiated from a class, that has returned a list of objects with attributes such as size, mean- and max-intensity and so on. What i wanted was to make a function where i can filter this list of objects based on their attributes, but allowing it to be through a kwarg instead of hardcoding all filter options.

```
def filtering(objects, **kwargs):
   return [obj for obj in objects if obj[kwarg[key]]==kwarg[value]]
```

So the above will ofcourse not work, but i inteded it to show what i had hoped to make. Basically being able to input a key value pair as kwarg to filter a list of objects by their attributes. My reason for doing so is that tere is more than 100 attributes, and the alternative as i see it is to hardcode the option for filters.

I hope someone can help me resolve this or point me in any direction that makes more sense.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get what you want:

```
def filtering(objects, **kwargs):
   return [obj for obj in objects if any(getattr(obj, key, None) == value for key, value in kwargs.items())]
```

this will filter objects for which at least one of the attributes match kwarg value.
If you want to match all kwargs supplied, then replace `any` with `all`.

Comment: Amazing! This was just what i was looking for! And it was the all implementation was exactly what i was going for but would have been happy with any too